# Script "Ctrl+A" execution

Tags: bash

I want my Bash script to execute a "Ctrl+A" on a 'file' from Bash code and not keyboard. In my script it performs a: wget 'file.pdf', then evince 'file.pdf'. I then have to issue a keyboard "Ctrl+A" (for Select All", then 'copy'; 'paste' (to clipboard) in order to get the text. I want to have the script issue the "CTRL+A" ??

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what your actual objective is. Do you want to download a PDF file and convert it to text?

Comment: If you really want to script keypresses you can use `xdotool`.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is 'pdftotext':
https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext

```
wget file.pdf
pdftotext file.pdf file.txt
```

That's all!